# How is the Cech complex a subcomplex of the Vietoris Rips complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Wikipedia states: The [Čech complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_complex) is a subcomplex of the [Vietoris–Rips complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietoris%E2%80%93Rips_complex).

And they reference [Ghrist](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Eghrist/notes.html) which essentially makes the definitions:

> Given a finite point cloud $X$ and $\epsilon >0$, we construct the
> Čech complex $C_\epsilon(X)$ as follows: Take the elements of $X$ as
> the vertex set of  $C_\epsilon(X)$. Then, for each $\sigma\subset X$, let $\sigma\in  C_\epsilon(X)$ if the set of
> $\epsilon$-balls centered at points of $\sigma$ has a nonempty
> intersection.

Similarly,

> The Vietoris Rips Complex of scale $\epsilon$ on $X$ is an abstract
> simplicial complex whose simplices are all finite collections of
> points in $X$ of pairwise distance $\leq\epsilon$.

Ghrist also makes the claim that the Cech complex is a subcomplex of the Vietoris Rips complex $VR_\epsilon$, and sometimes a proper subcomplex (p.30), but does not state any scale for the Cech complex in that statement. I then take it as implicit that this means that $C_\epsilon(X)\leq VR_\epsilon(X)$, i.e. for the same $\epsilon$. But, I do not see how this can be:

Just simply take $X$ to be two points $x_1,x_2$ at distance $1$ from eachother. Then clearly $C_{0.6}(X)$ is two vertices and an edge, but $VR_{0.6}(X)$ is just two vertices.

**Question:** Either it seems it would be the other way round ($V\leq C$), or we have that $C_\epsilon\leq VR_{2\epsilon}$ or something. What is the relation, and/or what am I misunderstanding?

And, if it is, for example, $C_\epsilon\leq VR_{2\epsilon}$, what motivates a statement of the form 'The Čech complex is a subcomplex of the Vietoris–Rips complex' without any reference to scale?

Comment: The motivation probably includes that a good reader can figure out the proper reference to scale, as you have.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sure, but the reason I figured there was a misunderstanding lingering somewhere is that: It just seemed a bit arbitrary to say "...is a subcomplex..." if the inequality could equally well be reversed (and even is reversed for the same scale) depending on the scale. I felt there was some other motivation that I'd missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have shown, in general $C_\epsilon(Q)\leq VR_\epsilon(Q)$ is false. But in fact both

1. $C_\epsilon(Q)\leq VR_{2\epsilon}(Q)$
2. $VR_\epsilon(Q)\leq C_\epsilon(Q)$

are true. I am not sure whether 2. is true for an *arbitrary* metric space $(Q, d)$, but here we have $Q \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric. Thus, given $n$ points $q_i \in Q$ such that $\lvert q_i - q_j \rvert < \epsilon$ for all $i,j$, we define the barycenter $b = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}q_i$ of the $q_i$ and easily verify that $b \in \bigcap _{i=1}^n B_\epsilon(q_i)$: We have $$\lvert b - q_j \rvert = \lvert\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}q_i - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}q_j \rvert = \lvert\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}(q_i - q_j) \rvert = \lvert \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (q_i - q_j) \rvert \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert q_i - q_j \rvert\\  < \frac{1}{n} n \epsilon = \epsilon .$$

The statement

> The Čech complex is a subcomplex of the Vietoris–Rips complex $VR_\epsilon(Q)$

suggests that $C_\epsilon(Q)\leq VR_{\epsilon}(Q)$, but it needs a more flexible interpretation. This is 1.

The problem with Ghrist's exposition is that is does not become clear what the *purpose* of the Vietoris–Rips / Čech complex *really* is.

I think you need to know *Čech (co)homology* if you want to understand that point. Unfortunately Ghrist does not introduce this properly. He only defines the Čech homology groups of open covers of a space $X$. The Čech (co)homology groups of a space $X$ are defined as follows:

The set $\mathscr C(X)$ of all open covers of $X$ is partially ordered by refinement; this makes $\mathscr C(X)$ an *inverse system*. The Čech homology groups (cohomology groups) of $X$ are defined as the inverse limit (direct limit) of the Čech homology groups (cohomology groups) of the open covers of $X$.

A similar construction gives us the *Vietoris (co)homology groups* of $X$.

For the limit processes we do not need the full set $\mathscr C(X)$, any cofinal subsystem will do. If $X$ is compact, the coverings by balls of a fixed diameter form such a cofinal subsystem. Now the above arguments concerning the  Čech and Vietoris-Rips complexes show that the Čech and the Vietoris (co)homology groups agree.

This was a very rough explanation, but I hope it gives at least an *idea* what is going on here.

Comment: It most certainly do give me a better idea. I expected there to be more to the story basically (and I couldn't have hoped for a better answer). Regardless of what inequalities hold or not, does it also make sense to define these complexes for arbitrary distances? (i.e. non-neg, reflexive and symmetric real functions on $X^2$) Everywhere I find them, I only see them defined for $\mathbb{R}^n$ or possibly a metric space. I thought perhaps there's a reason for this other than that these are just the most common/useful examples.